# "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" in post method

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OABY.png)

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .models import note
from .serializers import noteSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def getroute(request):

    routes = [
       { 'Endpoint':'/note/',
        'method':'GET',
        'body':None,
        'description':'Returns an array of notes'},
         { 'Endpoint':'/note/id',
        'method':'GET',
        'body':None,
        'description':'Returns an single note object'},
        { 'Endpoint':'/note/create/',
        'method':'POST',
        'body':{'body':""},
        'description':'creates a single note object'},
        { 'Endpoint':'/note/id/update',
        'method':'PUT',
        'body':{'body':""},
        'description':'updates a single note object'},
        { 'Endpoint':'/note/id/delete',
        'method':'DELETE',
        'body':None,
        'description':'deletes a single note object'}
    ]
    return Response(routes)


@api_view(['POST'])
def createnote(request):
    print("request.data")
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = noteSerializer(data=data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getNotes(request):
    notes = note.objects.all().order_by('-updated')
    serializer = noteSerializer(notes,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
    


@api_view(['GET'])
def getNote(request,pk):
    notes = note.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = noteSerializer(notes,many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['PUT'])
def updatenote(request,pk):
    data =request.data
    notes =note.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = noteSerializer(instance=notes,data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['Delete'])
def deletenote(request,pk):
    notes = note.objects.get(id=pk)
    notes.delete()
    return Response("Note deleted")
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class note(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import note

class noteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = note
        fields = '__all__'
```

At first I used the `api/todo/create` url and it showed me "detail": "Method "GET" not allowed." and I added get method in the apiview of create and then I tried post a todo content through the Django rest api page and "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" shows up but if I try the same with react, the post method works.

Comment: You may have typo in your json, check there is no any commas at the end, you forgot to add comma between objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSONParser()`. However, Django Rest Framework automatically parses the request data into a dictionary, so you don't need to parse it manually. You can access the data directly from `request.data`. Removing the line `data =` `JSONParser().parse(request)` should resolve this issue.

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def createnote(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = noteSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```